# How to connect with hibernate file to SQL server database?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have a problem because I don't know how to connect to SQL server with hibernate file I try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database Connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=RentApp</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">LAPTOP-SJJ2BT5V\Konrad</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>

        <!-- Echo SQL wyswietlenie zapytania tabeli bazy danych -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- SQL Dialect implementacja silnika bazo danego  -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>

        <!-- database intialize -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- mappings -->
        <mapping class="pl.edu.wszib.model.Vehicle" />
        <mapping class="pl.edu.wszib.model.User" />
        <mapping class="pl.edu.wszib.model.GroupVehicle" />
        <mapping class="pl.edu.wszib.model.Rent" />
        <mapping class="pl.edu.wszib.model.Buy" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

[image]

In SQL server my database name is RentApp and I use windows authentication in the Microsoft SQL Server.
So

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.username">LAPTOP-SJJ2BT5V\Konrad</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
```

username must be from Microsoft SQL Server?
And I use in my pom

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.2.jre11</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have an error right that but I have username: LAPTOP-SJJ2BT5V\Konrad

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'LAPTOP-SJJ2BT5V\Konrad'.
```

I try this

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Test;integratedSecurity=true</property>
```

But I have error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database Connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Test;integratedSecurity=true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">LAPTOP-SJJ2BT5V\Konrad</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>

        <!-- Echo SQL wyswietlenie zapytania tabeli bazy danych -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- SQL Dialect implementacja silnika bazo danego  -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>

        <!-- database intialize -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- mappings -->
        <mapping class="pl.edu.wszib.model.Vehicle" />
        <mapping class="pl.edu.wszib.model.User" />
        <mapping class="pl.edu.wszib.model.GroupVehicle" />
        <mapping class="pl.edu.wszib.model.Rent" />
        <mapping class="pl.edu.wszib.model.Buy" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and i must download sqljdbc_auth.dll and put this file to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin